# spring-transactions - Reading inserted data in the same transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-transactions

I am new to hibernate transactions. I am looking for a solution to problem explained below,

I have a method annotated with `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`, as part of which I am inserting some data to the DB in first step, now once inserted, I want to read the same inserted data in the same transaction after execution of few steps, but since the current transaction is not completed yet, the inserted data is not yet committed, therefore its giving me null values when I try to read it in the subsequent steps.

Below is the sample code

```
 @Autowired
 private List<Step<DomainObject>> listOfStepsToExecute;

 @Transactional
  public void execute(Event event) {
    
    listOfStepsToExecute
        .forEach(step -> {
          step.execute(orderDetails);
        });
  }
```

Please explain how this can be achieved.

Answer (score -1):

Hi Rahul **PlatformTransactionManager**   It can work for you read this documentation https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/spring-transaction-management-transactional-in-depth

Comment: Hey @Zaur - not sure how this exactly helps to achieve this. Can you plz elaborate?

Comment: You will be able to handle the process as you wish. Transaction prosess

Comment: I don't have time or I would share the code blog but I guided it I think it will be useful